# Bounding the sum of "almost" factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I am analyzing the complexity of an algorithm and the result is the sum of n products. Product 1 is the factorial. Product 2 is the factorial divided by 2. Product 3 is the factorial divided by 3 etc. Can we bound this in a most sophisticated way than the obvious n*(n!) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sum is $n!\sum _{i=1}^n \frac 1i=n!H_n$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  It is about $\log n+ \gamma$, with $\gamma \approx 0.577$